# iText in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I want to use [iText](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to write data to pdf.

Assembles that I've added are

1. iTextdotNET.dll
2. Gnu.Classpath.Core.dll

But the problem that I am facing is

- Error 1   The type 'java.io.OutputStream' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'vjslib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
- Error 2   The type 'java.io.Serializable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'vjslib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

What I understood is: It requires j#.

Now what to do?

Comment: Doesn't look like J# to me, looks like straight-up Java.

Comment: vjs and publicKeyToken says its not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of the .NET version of iText ahve just a single DLL called itextsharp.dll with no dependencies on J# libraries or anything like that.

BTW If you're doing anything non-trivial, look for the mailing list and order the book now (the book goes deep but remains approachable)

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) two .NET ports of iText. It looks like you've got [iText.NET](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/). Grab the latest release of [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) and your dependency worries should be over.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) rather than iText.Net.  iText.Net hasn't been updated in quite a while, while ITextSharp is relatively up-to-date and works seamlessly with newer versions of the .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the framework is your project targeting?  It looks like it is trying to use the .NET 1.1 versions of the libraries.

Comment: I am using asp.net MVC. with fw 3.5 sp1

Answer (score 0):

That gnu.classpath.core.dll is part of IKVM, isn't it? You should not need that unless you want to use the Java version of iText. (and if you do, install a JRE and set the path to it correctly) You are trying to use the .Net version, so remove that reference and see if it works.